# Monodroid - Draw an overlay and put a button over a camera preview

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Starting with this sample:  https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ApiDemo/Graphics/CameraPreview.cs

How would I add a view finder (just a rectangle) and a button to the preview?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `FrameLayout` like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">    

        <android.view.SurfaceView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/preview"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </android.view.SurfaceView>

           <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="60dp" 
android:background="#FFFFFF" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

                <ImageView android:scaleType="centerCrop" android:src="@drawable/some_drawable" android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:clickable="true"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/my_button"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Wrapping everything in the `FrameLayout` is one way to simply stack views on top of the `SurfaceView`. Use a similar approach to add your viewfinder.