# Xamarin.Android - How to draw a frame over the picture capture preview?

Tags: xamarin.android

I have an app that uses the xam.media.plugin to take picture in a cross platform way, but I need to draw a frame over the picture visualization (picture preview).. so, this way, the user knows how to pisitioning the object inside the frame we need..

Is there a way or a cross plugin to do that? Or the logic should be placed inside the android project, so it is more flexible?

Has someone done something like that already?

Any help would be really great.

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: ohh yes you can get it from any barcode scanning UI code. For example at this time I have this file link https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/blob/master/Samples/Forms/Core/CustomScanPage.cs  otherwise you can search any barcode library & just use their UI part only

Comment: Have you already checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829991/monodroid-draw-an-overlay-and-put-a-button-over-a-camera-preview. You basically need to put a framelayout with a surfaceview